# Where to search for 60's USSR literature

Tags: mathematics, literature-search, russia

I am looking for some 60's Russian literature. I have found citations of the sources, but I cannot find places to access them. The university library said they cannot help me. I would appreciate any help in locating these papers, either in their original Russian language or in a translation. Here are the citations:

[1] E.L. Burshtein and L.S. Solov'ev, The Hamiltonian of averaged motion, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 139 (1961), 855-858; English transl. in Soviet Math. Dokl. 2 (1961).

[2] V.P. Vcherashnyuk, On the question of integrability of canonical equations with the help of the principle of averaging, in: Proc. Scientific Conference, Inst. Math., Ukrainian Academy of Sciences, Kiev 1963, pp. 20-24. (Russian)

[3] A.M. Fedorchenko, The method of canonical averaging in the theory of non-linear oscillations, Ukrain. Mat. Zh. 9 (1957), 220-224.

All three are cited in [A M Samoilenko 1994 Russ. Math. Surv. 49 109](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM1994v049n05ABEH002432/meta)

I know the stackexchange is not really meant for this question. So, if you know a place on the internet where this would be more relevant, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [4] was published in Ukrains’kyi Matematychnyi Zhurnal, but the [online archives](https://umj.imath.kiev.ua/index.php/umj/issue/archive/4) lack anything from 1954-1991.

Comment: @Anyon The year 1957 (volume 9) is not available :/

Comment: Are you at a major university? Surprising (if so) that the librarian has no resources. I wonder if anyone can contact the library at Charles University in Prague. Or somewhere in Poland.

Comment: @Buffy Rather small university in Germany. The library seemed quite certain they could not help me.

Comment: Sometimes you have to go (physically or not) to a place with a larger library, or a library with more specialized collections. Incidentally, your profile mentions Leuven, and KU Leuven's libraries appear to have the volume in question of Doklady akademii nauk SSSR that contains [1].

Comment: I changed university recently. But that KU Leuven has a copy is good news. I could ask some old colleagues. Thanks @Anyon. Is there some website you used to find out which universities has a physical copy of a journal volume?

Comment: @drandran12 In general, WorldCat.org can be very useful, but tends not to be as good with (journal) titles in Russian. In this case, I tried KU Leuven's library search directly after seeing your profile. Your librarian should presumably know if there is some database with great coverage of German libraries.

Comment: The *Doklady* should not be overly hard, that is quite a mainstream journal; for instance, the University of Konstanz has it for 1961(!) to 1978. The Ukrainian journals are likely much harder. It may make sense to go directly to the online presence of a Ukrainian university. Journals in German libraries should be findable in [the ZDB catalogue](https://zdb-katalog.de/index.xhtml); it may be necessary to play around with transcriptions of titles originally in non-Latin alphabets, especially for "older" journals from times when the "German" transcription may have been different than in English.

Comment: LOL, I see in your profile that you are in Konstanz. Head down to the UB on level BS 2 and look for signature mat 2/s65 for that *Doklady* issue.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Now I'm wondering what made the librarian claim they could not help the OP with at least a part of their request.